# "Changes made" notifycation

Tags: blackberry

in my application I have some screens with focusable custom buttons, wich pushing another screens with another focusable custom buttons and so on. When I press blackberry's "back" button anter pushing 2-3 screens, it sometimes appear notification with message "Changes made", and options "save", "discard" and "cancel". **Why is this? How can I avoid it?** all I did is moved focus and pressed buttons.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can avoid this overriding onclose() and setdirty(false).

```
public boolean onClose() {
        setDirty(false);
        return super.onClose();
    }
```

Comment: that code is wrong: screens not clozing if I do so. But you guide me to right direction: `super.close();` insteed of `setDirty(false);` soles my problem

Comment: I think setdirty(false); is required to suppress the annoying save dialog box. It appears because the screen's fields are dirtied. Any glad to know your problem solved